# Create a Google Chrome New Tab-based content page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, content-pages

I know that the title of this question i am putting here may be confusing, but i will explain what is about.

I have this web application in ASP.NET, where among all pages i have created already, i would like to have a page for each user when they log in, where in this page users will add , delete and sort their personal services(e.g., Facebook, Twitter), and have an overall overview of what services they have chosen.

This overview i want it to be like the New Tab overview in Google Chrome where we see the previous links we have visited, and we can also drag/move them, sort them or delete them.

I would like to do the same in my web application, in a content page, which for each user will be different since they will log in to their account. The services that each user will choose to include in his account will be stored in a custom table called Services in my database where the Membership provider is installed, and every time users log in to their account, the personal services they have chosen will be read form the database and presented in this content page in the form of New Tab in Google Chrome.

My question is how would you recommend that i start, or if you have any ideas about this drag thing how it can be done. I completely have no clue or any approach in my mind of how to go with this. Any ideas and suggestions are most welcomed

This is the last part that i have to finish for my web application to be completed.

Thank you very much !